# mysql: select from two tables through a lookup table

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a db that has the following tables:

problems-->p_index, name, description

solutions-->s_index, name, description

Any given problem may have many solutions.
Similarly, any solution may apply to multiple problems.

Therefore, I have a lookup table called 'kadai':

kadai-->problem, solution

where problem and solution are integers that correspond to the p_index and s_index.

How do I select problems.name, solutions.name given an integer that corresponds to the 
problem. eg:

```
SELECT problems.name, solutions.name FROM problems, solutions
INNER JOIN problems ON kadai.problem = problems.p_index
INNER JOIN solution ON kadai.solution = solutions.s_index
WHERE problems.p_index = 2;
```

This is one of a long line of unsuccessful solutions.
How is this accomplished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT problems.name, solutions.name FROM problems
INNER JOIN kadai ON kadai.problem = problems.p_index
INNER JOIN solution ON kadai.solution = solutions.s_index
WHERE problems.p_index = 2;
```

Join "problems" with "kadai" and "kadai" with "solutions".